# Why can't I connect to a Cisco wireless access point?

Tags: 10.04, wireless, ubuntu-netbook, cisco

I'm running a Lucid Netbook Remix on my Dell Inspiron 600m and I was not able to connect to the wireless network at the Hacker Dojo in Mountain View yesterday. There were plenty of other people on the network - MS, Mac, and Linux boxes - but my laptop would never get an ip address. I can connect to my home network, which is open, and I've never had a problem connecting at the coffee shop, which uses WPA. The Hacker Dojo is running WPA and we checked the password a number of times but got no love. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**Additional Info:**

```
$iwlist eth1 scan

eth1      Scan completed :
      Cell 01 - Address: EC:C8:82:FA:63:92
                ESSID:"HackerDojo-gwifi"
                Protocol:IEEE 802.11g
                Mode:Master
                Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                Encryption key:on
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                          11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s
                          48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Quality:62  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                Extra: Last beacon: 280ms ago

      Cell 02 - Address: 00:18:4D:24:08:61
                ESSID:"Green Zone"
                Protocol:IEEE 802.11bg
                Mode:Master
                Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
                Encryption key:on
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                          9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s
                          48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Quality:23  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                Extra: Last beacon: 11516ms ago

      Cell 03 - Address: 08:17:35:32:6E:13
                ESSID:"\x00"
                Protocol:IEEE 802.11g
                Mode:Master
                Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                Encryption key:on
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                          11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s
                          48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Quality:71  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                Extra: Last beacon: 2760ms ago

      Cell 04 - Address: EC:C8:82:FA:63:90
                ESSID:"HackerDojo"
                Protocol:IEEE 802.11g
                Mode:Master
                Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                Encryption key:on
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                          11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s
                          48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Quality:61  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                Extra: Last beacon: 772ms ago

      Cell 05 - Address: 08:17:35:32:6E:11
                ESSID:"HackerDojo-Presenter"
                Protocol:IEEE 802.11g
                Mode:Master
                Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                Encryption key:on
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                          11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s
                          48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Quality:65  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                Extra: Last beacon: 3308ms ago

      Cell 06 - Address: 08:17:35:32:7E:31
                ESSID:"HackerDojo-Presenter"
                Protocol:IEEE 802.11g
                Mode:Master
                Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                Encryption key:on
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                          11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s
                          48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Quality:88  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                Extra: Last beacon: 1668ms ago

      Cell 07 - Address: 38:E7:D8:01:46:1E
                ESSID:"JWS_Incredible"
                Protocol:IEEE 802.11bg
                Mode:Master
                Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                Encryption key:on
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                          11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s
                          48 Mb/s; 500 kb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Quality:31  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                Extra: Last beacon: 2848ms ago

      Cell 08 - Address: 08:17:35:32:6E:10
                ESSID:"HackerDojo"
                Protocol:IEEE 802.11g
                Mode:Master
                Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                Encryption key:on
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                          11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s
                          48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Quality:67  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                Extra: Last beacon: 7848ms ago

      Cell 09 - Address: 08:17:35:32:7E:30
                ESSID:"HackerDojo"
                Protocol:IEEE 802.11g
                Mode:Master
                Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                Encryption key:on
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                          11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s
                          48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Quality:85  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                Extra: Last beacon: 8300ms ago

      Cell 10 - Address: 08:17:35:32:6E:12
                ESSID:"HackerDojo-gwifi"
                Protocol:IEEE 802.11g
                Mode:Master
                Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                Encryption key:on
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                          11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s
                          48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Quality:68  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                Extra: Last beacon: 232ms ago

      Cell 11 - Address: 08:17:35:32:7E:32
                ESSID:"HackerDojo-gwifi"
                Protocol:IEEE 802.11g
                Mode:Master
                Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                Encryption key:on
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                          11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s
                          48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Quality:86  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                Extra: Last beacon: 168ms ago

      Cell 12 - Address: EC:C8:82:FA:63:91
                ESSID:"HackerDojo-Presenter"
                Protocol:IEEE 802.11g
                Mode:Master
                Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                Encryption key:on
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                          11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s
                          48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Quality:62  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                Extra: Last beacon: 7408ms ago

$iwconfig eth1

eth1      unassociated  ESSID:"HackerDojo-gwifi"  Nickname:"ipw2100"
      Mode:Managed  Channel=0  Access Point: Not-Associated   
      Bit Rate:0 kb/s   Tx-Power:16 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: Because Cisco laid off 6,500 people yesterday, most being the miniature elfs that live in your routers to make sure they work correctly and to do maintenance and up keep on them.

Answer (score 1):

enable "guest mode" for the ssid on the cisco ap and you will recive ;)